# Display Data in Graph Panel for some Custom Range for time in X-Axis

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana, influxdb

I am very new to Grafana, just started understanding since yesterday. I am using InfluxDB as a Datasource. I actually liked Grafana, but I could not able to achieve simple scenario.

I wanna show some data based on some "time" custom range in X-Axis. Although I could be able to select custom Date globally, but I wanna select time range (say, I wanna see graph of data between 5 Pm to 7 Pm of some column data for Jan 11, 2020), how can I achieve this in Graph Panel? I 've selected custom date using Date Picker as "Jan 11", but not understanding how to view data for some specific custom range in Graph Panel.

After searching, I found something like: $__from , $__to, but could not able to understand how to use it in Graph Panel. I mean here: `https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/`

I will be glad if anyone could be able to look into my above issue. Thank you!

Comment: Any idea for above?

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have $timeFilter in your WHERE clause

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/#the-timefilter-or-timefilter-variable

For Example

`SELECT SUM(*) from measurement.whatever WHERE $timeFilter`

Say my time range on the Dashboard is "Last 7 Days"

The above would expand to

`SELECT SUM(*) from measurement.whatever WHERE time >=now() -7d`

Comment: I didnt get you,  now() -7d means graph shows last 7 days data, right?

Comment: In my measurements table in InfluxDB, I actually have time column values in the form of epoch (ie., something like this: https://www.influxdata.com/wp-content/uploads/telegraf-writing-data.png), I wanna show time range between first and last epoch in X- Axis, instead of showing whole 24 hrs of Jan 11, 2020 in X-Axis, Is this possible?

Comment: i dont believe so. The Graph Panel will automatically scale based on the Global Time selected for the dashboard. A feature request for this functionality is in: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6288

Comment: okay thank U, not sure whether they gonna implement this feature